Windows Error: 'This app can't run on your PC' When Trying to Run a Maven-Built Project

I'm developing a web application using Maven and Angular, and I'm trying to run it on a Windows machine. However, when I attempt to start the application, I encounter the following error message:
This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.
the project {thingsboard} using Maven and the error occurs when I try to execute an .exe generated in the build process. Here's a brief overview of what I was doing when this error appeared:
Running Maven build commands.
Executing the generated .exe file in the target directory.
Here are the specifications of my development environment:
OS: Windows 11
Node.js version: v20.12.2
Maven version: Apache Maven 3.9.6
Java version: 11.0.22
I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:
Running the application as an administrator.
Ensuring my PATH environment variable is set correctly.
Could someone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to fix it?
enter image description here

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Had the exact same issue. Reverting from node v20.12.2 down to v.18.20.3 did the trick on my end. Give it a try and see if that helps.
